# Show Yesterday and Today's date together javascript

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to display yesterday's date and Today's date simultaneously on my Dashboard in a .  For e.g. if **today's date** is `30 june 2019`, it should show `29 june 2019` as **yesterday** or if **today's date** is `1 july 2019`, it should display `30 june 2019` as **yesterday date**.

I tried calculating the previous day and date on the basis of today's date but it not changing everytime automatically. I got stuck in the looping functions.

```
getToday(){

        const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];


        var dateToday = new Date().getDate();
        let monthToday = monthNames[new Date().getMonth()];
        let yearToday = new Date().getFullYear();

    }


getYesterday(){
    // var dateToday = new Date().getDate();
    //let dateYesterday = new Date(Date.now() - 86400000).getDate();
    //let monthYesterday = new Date(Date.now() - 86400000).getMonth();
    //console.log(dateYesterday,monthYesterday)



   //another approach I tried following
   var dateToday = new Date().getDate();
   var yesterday = dateToday.setDate(dateToday.getDate() - 1);
}

componentDidMount(){

            this.getToday();
            this.getYesterday();
}
```

Please help to complete this.

Comment: You can use `.setDate(-1)` to change a date to the day before.

Comment: I tried. But it says `dateToday.getDate is not a function`

Comment: Well then you probably used it wrong, but without you showing us what exactly you did, we can’t really tell you what that might be.

Comment: @04FS I edited my post for reference.

Comment: You need to call this method on the Date object instance, not on what getDate has returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need:

```
var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate() -1);
```

d has the yesterday date.

```
getFullYear()   Get the year as a four digit number (yyyy)
getMonth()  Get the month as a number (0-11)
getDate()   Get the day as a number (1-31)
getHours()  Get the hour (0-23)
getMinutes()    Get the minute (0-59)
getSeconds()    Get the second (0-59)
getMilliseconds()   Get the millisecond (0-999)
getTime()   Get the time (milliseconds since January 1, 1970)
getDay()    Get the weekday as a number (0-6)
Date.now()  Get the time. ECMAScript 5.
```

Example:

```
var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate() -1);
monthYesterday = d.getMonth(); // you get the month of yesterday
yearYesterday = d.getFullYear(); // you get the year of yesterday (format yyyy)
```

Comment: It prints me some numerical as 1561894531543. How Can I further use it to display  today's and yesterday's date both so that it keep changing dynamically

Comment: @bubble-cord that's just the return value from the `setDate` function. `d` has the `Date` object.

Comment: @bubble-cord the setDate method returns the new timestamp in milliseconds. If you want a readable date - then format the date object `d` afterwards, the same way as you did before.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an working example;
I've simplified getToday as well.

https://jsfiddle.net/f0pwhj3L/9/

```
getToday(){
        var dateToday = new Date();
        const month = dateToday.toLocaleString('en-us', { month: 'long' });        
    }


getYesterday(){
   const dateYesterday = new Date();
   dateYesterday.setDate(-1);
   const dayYesterday = dateYesterday.getDate();
   const monthYesterday = dateYesterday.getMonth();

}

componentDidMount(){

            this.getToday();
            this.getYesterday();
}
```